# How to use dynamic SQL queries from an .ini file?

Tags: mysql, delphi, dynamic, ini

I'm a newbie in Delphi and software programming.

I want to find some advice for using queries from a `.ini` file.

It is my purpose that when I choose some file names in a DBGrid first, and click a button which show file names that I selected, and if they are correct then I click 'ok' to execute a query with the file names.

In this situation, the file names will change every time I select them. So, how can I execute the query in `.ini` file to get dynamic results?

First, here is the text in the `Queries.ini` file:

```ini
[Query]
QSELECTEDFN=SELECT * FROM TEST_01 WHERE FILE_NAME IN (:FILE_NAME);
```

Here is my code:

```pascal
ini := TIniFile.Create('C:\file dir\Queries.ini');
try
  qSlctdByFN := ini.ReadString('QUERY', 'QSELECTEDFN', '');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := qSlctdByFN;
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('FILE_NAME').Value := slselectedFN.CommaText;
  ADOQuery1.Active := true;
finally
  ini.Free;
end;
```

When I selected `1.txt`, `2.txt` then the query should be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TEST_01 WHERE FILE_NAME IN ('1.txt,2.txt');
```

When I selected only `3.txt` then the query should be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TEST_01 WHERE FILE_NAME IN ('3.txt');
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, one can't use IN with parameters. I may well be wrong. You will have to build a string of filenames then add this string to the query without the parameter.

Comment: `'1.txt,2.txt'` is one text literal, not two. You have to pay attention to really list two literals, like: `'1.txt', '2.txt'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an SQL parameter with an `IN` clause. It takes a list of values, and a single parameter can't provide a list.

Your 1st example with 2 file names is actually wrong. It would need to be more like this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_01 WHERE FILE_NAME IN ('1.txt','2.txt');
```

Note the difference between `('1.txt,2.txt')` (a single string) and `('1.txt','2.txt')` (a list of strings).

So, to handle this, you are going to have to build up the replacement list manually, and then you can use [`StringReplace()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StringReplace) to replace `':FILE_NAME'` in the SQL with that list, eg:

```pascal
ini := TIniFile.Create('C:\file dir\Queries.ini');
try
  qSlctdByFN := ini.ReadString('QUERY', 'QSELECTEDFN', ''); 
finally
  ini.Free;
end;

files := QuotedStr(slSelectedFN[0]);
for i := 1 to Pred(slSelectedFN.Count) do
  files := files + ',' + QuotedStr(slSelectedFN[i];

ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := StringReplace(qSlctdByFN, ':FILE_NAME', files, []);

ADOQuery1.Active := true;
```

Comment: However, that eliminates the security purpose of prepared statements - there's no guarantee that escaping a `'` is enough. A slightly better approach is to use a rough estimate, like 50 placeholders and then, as per your needs, use ~7 of them and fill the remaining 43 ones with empty values.

Comment: An alternative solution that might seem like overkill is creating a new table with two fields - an autoincrement primary key and a string. The chosen file names are inserted into this table (the name goes into the string field, obviously). The original query includes a join to this table - no need for parameters,

Comment: @No'amNewman that just moves the problem, it doesn't eliminate it. You would still have to get the file names into a query to insert them into that other table.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Whilst that's true, it's replacing an intractable problem with one that can be solved.